# How can I redirect to the next page I clicked after login PHP

Tags: php, authentication, redirect

Imagine I have a page called `index.php` and several other pages that are linked to it. Any link on `index.php` requires logging in to access it. All the links on `index.php` should redirect me to another page but only after a successful login.

How can I go to any link I clicked automatically after I log in successfully. An example is, when I click on `xxxxxxxxxxx.php`, it takes me to the login page first and, after I successfully login, I would prefer it takes me to `xxxxxxxxxxx.php` for that instance.

Comment: So you see the links, can click on them, but only redirect after login? And how do you prevent direct acces to those pages when I can see the url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a solution and it works. I'm not quite sure how safe it is but check it out

First, if the person is not logged in I redirect to the login page with the requested page set to `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];`.

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
    header('Location: ../login?next='.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    $db = null;
    die();
}
```

Then is the person logs in successfully I set the requested page to the `header()` if it exists else I proceed to the dashboard.

```
if (isset($_GET['next'])) {
    $location_redirect = $_GET['next'];
} else {
    $location_redirect = "member/dashboard";
}
header("location: $location_redirect");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this in two method

1. while redirecting to login page add current link as get parameter like 
   redirect to `login.php?from=xxxxxxxxxxx.php`
2. or using `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` from login page it will give the the priovious page url

Comment: And now I type as url directly `domain/xxxxx.php`. No login required at all.

Comment: u need to set session after login success and distroy it when logout

Comment: and check ur session every page to verify user is logged in

Comment: Obvious. Your answer isn't wrong but OP isn't mentioning anything about how he logs in and maintains state. And without that, this isn't a solution.

Comment: @michel is correct, my answer touches on that OP needs to set sessions and then uses them to validate where users can navigate

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution i got based on your requirements:

in any page you don't want a user to access unless he is logged in you must do the following

```
 <?php 
 if(!isset($_SESSION['activeUser'])){
 echo "please login to view this page";
 header("refresh:3; url=login.php"); // you can set how many seconds you want before redirecting the user
  die();
  }
  ?>
```

in your login page, you  need to setup a session named for example `$_SESSION['activeUser']`, in which you can validate where a user can and can not enter.

Side note, users should not be able to see links that you don't want them to click on unless they are logged in. my answer above is for validating when a user tries to access a page in your website from the url.